# Upload CSV file into postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upload a CSV file into PostgreSQL and I get this error message:
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa0
CONTEXT:  COPY employees, line 95
SQL state: 22021
First I create the table:

```
Create table employees (EMPLOYEE_ID int, NAME varchar (100), TITLE varchar (100), JOBFAMILY varchar (5), RC int, TMREG numeric(1000,2),TMNONREG numeric(1000,2), PUGET numeric(1000,2), EDS numeric(1000,2), HOLDCO numeric(1000,2),TMEP numeric(1000,2), Total numeric(1000,2), CATEGORY int, TMEPDED varchar(3), ACTIVITY varchar(100))

Then I try to pull the data:
COPY employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, TITLE, JOBFAMILY, RC, TMREG, TMNONREG, PUGET, EDS, HOLDCO, TMEP, Total, CATEGORY, TMEPDED, ACTIVITY)
FROM 'C:\Jorge\Project\Source\employees.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

and I get the above error message.
Any help please?
JOrge

Comment: This generally happens when the file being pulled in is not the same encoding as the server. In `psql` do: 1) `show lc_ctype ; 2) `show client_encoding ;`. Also what OS and version are working in and what is its encoding? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Thanks then what should I do?

Comment: You have not provided the information so it is hard to say what to do from here?

Comment: @JorgeTorres how a re NUlls stored in csv as NULL or 'NULL'.???

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
COPY employees (EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, TITLE, JOBFAMILY, RC, TMREG, TMNONREG, PUGET, 
EDS, HOLDCO, TMEP, Total, CATEGORY, TMEPDED, ACTIVITY)
FROM 'C:\Jorge\Project\Source\employees.csv'
DELIMITER ',' 
NULL
CSV HEADER;
```

You would also have to specify Null as columns in the csv.